# Syntax of Intel compiler while compiling C++ program on Linux server

Tags: c++, linux, intel, eigen

I am a newbie to shell and compiling C++ program on Linux.

I have a C++ program and I am used to compile it with G++ withe the following command:

`g++ lapack.cpp generators.cpp SimpleRNG.cpp testabc.cpp -O3 -o examplexi.o;​`

That command works fine and testabc.cpp needs to call function from Eigen library, however, while I tried to used the following command with the intel compiler:

```
icpc lapack.cpp generators.cpp SimpleRNG.cpp testabc.cpp -O3 -o examplexi.o;​
```

There were a lot of errors and here I only picked one of them and put it below:

```
  Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>>, const Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 5>>>>]" at line 274 of "testabc.cpp"
```

I didn't find anything about the special syntax of Intel compiler, can anyone help me out here?

Thank you very much!

Xi

Ps:

Actually I found that all the error messages are warning and the program can compile finally. But the all these warning messages are still annoying so here I post the first couple of lines here and wish you can help me out!

```
eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h(453): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"
  general_matrix_vector_product
  ^
      detected during:
        instantiation of "void Eigen::internal::gemv_selector<2, 0, true>::run(const ProductType &, Dest &, ProductType::Scalar) [with ProductType=Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>, 4>, Dest=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, false, true>]" at line 340
        instantiation of "void Eigen::GeneralProduct<Lhs, Rhs, 4>::scaleAndAddTo(Dest &, Eigen::GeneralProduct<Lhs, Rhs, 4>::Scalar) const [with Lhs=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Rhs=Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>, Dest=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, false, true>]" at line 124 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Core/ProductBase.h"
        instantiation of "void Eigen::ProductBase<Derived, Lhs, Rhs>::scaleAndAddTo(Dest &, Eigen::ProductBase<Derived, Lhs, Rhs>::Scalar) const [with Derived=Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>, 4>, Lhs=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Rhs=Eigen::Transpose<const
                  Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>, Dest=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, false, true>]" at line 121 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Core/ProductBase.h"
        instantiation of "void Eigen::ProductBase<Derived, Lhs, Rhs>::subTo(Dest &) const [with Derived=Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>, 4>, Lhs=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Rhs=Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>,
                  Dest=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, false, true>]" at line 87 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Core/NoAlias.h"
        instantiation of "ExpressionType &Eigen::NoAlias<ExpressionType, StorageBase>::operator-=(const Eigen::ProductBase<ProductDerived, Lhs, Rhs> &) [with ExpressionType=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, 1, false, true>, StorageBase=Eigen::MatrixBase, ProductDerived=Eigen::GeneralProduct<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>,
                  4>, Lhs=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, -1, -1, false, true>, Rhs=Eigen::Transpose<const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, 1, -1, false, true>>]" at line 219 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "MatrixType::Index Eigen::internal::llt_inplace<1>::unblocked(MatrixType &) [with MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>]" at line 232 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "MatrixType::Index Eigen::internal::llt_inplace<1>::blocked(MatrixType &) [with MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>]" at line 282 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "bool Eigen::internal::LLT_Traits<MatrixType, 1>::inplace_decomposition(MatrixType &) [with MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>]" at line 311 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "Eigen::LLT<_MatrixType, _UpLo> &Eigen::LLT<_MatrixType, _UpLo>::compute(const Eigen::LLT<_MatrixType, _UpLo>::MatrixType &) [with _MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, _UpLo=1]" at line 101 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "Eigen::LLT<_MatrixType, _UpLo>::LLT(const Eigen::LLT<_MatrixType, _UpLo>::MatrixType &) [with _MatrixType=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>, _UpLo=1]" at line 373 of "eigen/Eigen/src/Cholesky/LLT.h"
        instantiation of "const Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar, Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::RowsAtCompileTime, Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::ColsAtCompileTime, <expression>, Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::MaxRowsAtCompileTime, Eigen::internal::traits<Derived>::MaxColsAtCompileTime>, 1> Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::llt() const [with Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1>]" at line 66 of "generators.cpp"
```

Comment: I can't see any _'special syntax'_?!? Do you mean the template parameter specifications in the `<>` angle brackets?

Comment: By 'special syntax', I mean the way to use intel compiler to compile c++ program, here <> is the from the source code of eigen. Does it matter?

Comment: The error message you included is not complete, that's just a fragment. Please include the complete first error message. (The first message is the most important, as the following errors are likely cascading failures.)

Comment: The most likely explanation (without seeing the full error messages) is that the Intel compiler is using different include paths.

Comment: _'Does it matter?'_ No you are just a little bit unclear about this point. But seemingly if you at least get the compiler errors the _command line syntax_ you use is fine.

Comment: @pdw,thank you for your comment, there are a lot of errors and warnings and they just flashed through screen. I can't see the first line and can only see the last few lines. Is there a way I can let the screen wait for me to copy the errors? Sorry for this dumb question....

Comment: Add `2> errors.txt` to the command line to write the errors to a file called `errors.txt`. (And drop the semi-colon from your command lines. It's a command separator, you don't need it at all if you are running only a single command.)

Comment: @pdw, thank you for your help, I exported the errors and edited the post.

Comment: Please show the very first error message completely. An error message may span multiple lines but it will likely contain the word "error" only once.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a warning. This one shouldn't cause any harm. Actually, are you sure that compilation fails? Maybe it just succeeds with a ton of warnings...

Comment: BTW it looks like you are using a very ancient version of Eigen. This warning was fixed in 2011. (Though maybe your program is simply that old and wouldn't work with a newer version of Eigen. I don't know.)

Comment: @pdw, thank you for your help! I downloaded the latest Eigen and no errors anymore. Can you answer this question and I'll accept your answer right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, these warnings/errors were caused by an old version of Eigen. Upgrading Eigen fixed the problem.